What's the intuition behind the definition of "rank of a tree"?
Let $T$ be a well-founded tree on $\mathbb{N}$, that is, the set of infinite branches of $T$ is empty. Define a function $\rho_T : T\to \mathbf{ON}$ inductively by $$\rho_T(u)=\sup\{\rho_T(v)+1: u\prec v, v\in T\},$$ where $u\prec v$ denotes that $u$ is an initial segment of $v$ or that $v$ is an extension of $u$, and $\mathbf{ON}$ is the class of all ordinals. We set $\rho_T(u)=0$ for terminal nodes $u\in T$. Let's denote the empty sequence in $\mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}}$ by $e$. Then the rank of $T$ is defined as $\rho(T)=\rho_T(e)$.
What is the intuitive idea behind this definition? I tried to understand it using the following examples. My main source of reference is the book A Course on Borel Sets by Srivastava.
Example. $\rho(T)=|s|$ if $T= \{s\upharpoonright i : i<|s|\}$, where $s\in \mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}}$ and $|s|$ is the length of $s$.
Let's use the definition $$\rho(T)=\rho_T(e)=\sup\{\rho_T(v)+1 : u\prec v, v\in T\}=\sup\{\rho_T(s\upharpoonright i)+1: i<|s|\}=\sup\{\rho_T((s_0))+1,\rho_T((s_0,s_1))+1,\ldots,\rho_T((s_0,s_1,\ldots,s_{|s|-1}))+1\},$$ where $s=(s_0,s_1,\ldots,s_{|s|-1})$. But $\rho_T((s_0,s_1,\ldots,s_{|s|-1}))=0$ as $(s_0,s_1,\ldots,s_{|s|-1})$ is a terminal node of $T$. So $\rho_T((s_0,s_1,\ldots,s_{|s|-2}))$ must be $1$ because the only extension of $(s_0,s_1,\ldots,s_{|s|-2})$ is $(s_0,s_1,\ldots,s_{|s|-1})$. Continuing in this manner, does it follows that $\rho_T(e)=|s|$, or rather $\rho(T)=|s|$.
I get the example. But what is the real idea behind this definition?
The second example is;
Example. $T=\{e\}\cup \{i0^j : j\leq i , i\in \mathbb{N}\}$. By the previous example it follows that $\rho(T)=\sup\{0,1,2,\ldots\}=\omega_0$.
I get this example too. But what's the real idea behind this definition?

It's just a generalisation to ordinals of the ordinary height of a finite tree.

The rank function serves to connect well-foundedness of trees to ordinals: A tree is well-founded iff it admits a strictly order-reversing map to the ordinals. The "if" direction is easy, and $\rho$ provides the example needed for the "only if" direction. In fact $\rho$ is the smallest such example; if $\rho'$ is another strictly order-reversing map from the tree to ordinals, then $\rho(u)\le\rho'(u)$ for all nodes $u$ of the tree.

Thanks, I think I see the point now.
